# Can not find web.Config of Empty SharePoint Project to Create an authorized type entry

Tags: visual-studio, custom-actions, workflow-activity

I'm trying to write a custom workflow action and after searching I find [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2010/12/26/develop-custom-workflow-activity-for-sharepoint-2010-workflow.aspx) article and some other that referred to it.
I follow the instructions step by step, but at the last step, author said:

> Create an authorized type entry for the CreateActivityDemo assembly (custom workflow activity assembly).

I can not find any web.config file to create authorized type entry in it.

Any suggestion or better reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it needs an  element in the AuthorizedTypes section of your web.config. The easiest way would be to open IIS manager (type in run - inetmgr) and search for your web site. then right-click and Explore, which automatically opens the Folder where files for that Web-Application are stored, you shall find the web.config there.

Alternatively you can go for \inetput\wwwroot\wss....your application, etc.

Follow this link exemplifying a programmaticaly way to add it automatically as soon as you deploy your solution (recomanded anyway!) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798302.aspx